# ui-router with global controllers not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm pretty amateur in angularjs, ui-router and MVC.
i have two views and controllers as two pages of my SPA.

i'm using mvc, web api, angularjs and ui-router in my project.

when i run my code, it doesn't work. and this error shown in browser console:

[enter link description here](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=AnbarUniversalSystemApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524stateProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A35621%2Fbundles%2Fangularjs%3Fv%3DiNEdxGlg7hpNdDMSbWGZhJYGnf2fZhkDcLF45sIws2M1%3A1%3A412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A35621%2Fbundles%2Fangularjs%3Fv%3DiNEdxGlg7hpNdDMSbWGZhJYGnf2fZhkDcLF45sIws2M1%3A1%3A16365%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A35621%2Fbundles%2Fangularjs%3Fv%3DiNEdxGlg7hpNdDMSbWGZhJYGnf2fZhkDcLF45sIws2M1%3A1%3A15337)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.u%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A35621%2Fbundles%2Fangularjs%3Fv%3DiNEdxGlg7hpNdDMSbWGZhJYGnf2fZhkDcLF45sIws2M1%3A1%3A15601)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20f%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A35621%2Fbundles%2Fangularjs%3Fv%3DiNEdxGlg7hpNdDMSbWGZhJYGnf2fZhkDcLF45sIws2M1%3A1%3A14806)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A35621%2Fbundles%2Fangularjs%3Fv%3DiNEdxGlg7hpNdDMSbWGZhJYGnf2fZhkDcLF45sIws2M1%3A1%3A14931%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A35621%2Fbundles%2Fangularjs%3Fv%3DiNEdxGlg7hpNdDMSbWGZhJYGnf2fZhkDcLF45sIws2M1%3A1%3A795)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A35621%2Fbundles%2Fangularjs%3Fv%3DiNEdxGlg7hpNdDMSbWGZhJYGnf2fZhkDcLF45sIws2M1%3A1%3A14712)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ur%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A35621%2Fbundles%2Fangularjs%3Fv%3DiNEdxGlg7hpNdDMSbWGZhJYGnf2fZhkDcLF45sIws2M1%3A1%3A16500)

this is my code:

Index.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AnbarUniversalSystemApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>sample</title>
</head>
<body>

<a ui-sref="DraftType">Draft Type</a>
<a ui-sref="Inv">Inv</a>

<div class="container body-content">
    <div ui-view></div>    
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ui-router")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AnbarUniversalSystemApp")
```

Inv.cshtml:

```
<div ng-controller="InvCtrl">
{{InvName}}
</div>
```

DraftType.cshtml:

```
<div ng-controller="DraftTypeCtrl">
{{DraftTypeName}}
</div>
```

AnbarUniversalSystemApp.js:

```
angular.module('AnbarUniversalSystemApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
var App = angular.module('AnbarUniversalSystemApp', []);
var configFunction = function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider,
$controllerProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);
$controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
$stateProvider
.state('Inv', {
    url: '/Payeh/Inv',
    templateUrl: 'Payeh/Inv.cshtml',
    controller: 'InvCtrl'
})
.state('DraftType', {
    url: '/Payeh/DraftType',
    templateUrl: 'Payeh/DraftType.cshtml',
    controller: 'DraftTypeCtrl'
})
}
configFunction.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
'$controllerProvider'];

App.config(configFunction);
App.controller('InvCtrl', InvCtrl);
App.controller('DraftTypeCtrl', DraftTypeCtrl);
```

InvCtrl.js:

```
function InvCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.InvName = "first Inv";
}

InvCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
```

DraftTypeCtrl.js:

```
function DraftTypeCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.DraftTypeName = "first Inv";
}

DraftTypeCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
```

RouteConfig.cs:

```
namespace AnbarUniversalSystem
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Inv",
            url: "Payeh/Inv",
            defaults: new { controller = "Payeh", action = "Inv" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DraftType",
            url: "Payeh/DraftType",
            defaults: new { controller = "Payeh", action = "DraftType" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can't open the error link. please copy your error message here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, As I don't have access to your code, I just can guess. the error is saying that `$stateProvider` has failed to load. so there is a problem with your dependencies.

change your `AnbarUniversalSystemApp.js` first two lines as below and check if it fixes your error :

**from :**

```
angular.module('AnbarUniversalSystemApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
var App = angular.module('AnbarUniversalSystemApp', []);
```

**to :**

```
var App = angular.module('AnbarUniversalSystemApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: yes. tried what you said but still gives same error.